# android 2d array to listview

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

so i've got this piece of code and i want it to output attr1 and attr2 in the listview, but the current error i get is: cannot resolve constructor. Here is the piece of code:

```
 private String[][] content = {
        {"attr1", "url1"},
        {"atrr2", "url2"}
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    for(int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, content[i][0]);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

Hopefully somebody could help me, thanks in advance (sorry for the bad english)

Comment: If you want just attr1, attr2 to be displayed, just use `String[] content={"attr1","attr2"};` First item will be attr1 and second one attr2

Comment: No. I still want to use the url's when the item is clicked

Comment: How would android set two texts in a single textView? Use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Comment: Why don't you create a custom class for `content` and use that to populate the `ListView`?

Comment: @Apurva I tried that but I still get the same error.

Comment: @iRuth How exactly would I do that (i'm still quite new with android developement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the creation of the list outside your for loop like so:

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    for(int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        adapter.add(content[i][0]);
    }
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can get the index of the clicked item and use that information to access your array again and get the second piece of information

Comment: Move `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` out of the loop